# pinax / django installation on virtual env, run on mod_wsgi

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, pinax

I tried to install Pinax development version by using pip and virtual environment.  It was running on 127.0.0.1:8000 very well.  However, when I deployed it on Apache 2 using mod_wsgi, it began to raise exception with the following error :

```
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

Any suggestions?

Note: I used postgresql as my database.

And here are the wsgi conf file for apache followed by the error log:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

<VirtualHost xx.xxx.xx.21:80> 
    ServerName www.example.com 
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin xxx@yahoo.com

WSGIDaemonProcess pinax threads=1 processes=25 python-path=/srv/www/django/myproj/lib/python2.6/site-packages 
WSGIProcessGroup pinax 

 WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/django/mysite/deploy/pinax.wsgi
   <Directory /srv/www/django/social/deploy>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
   </Directory>

    ErrorLog /srv/www/newsino/logs/error.log
   CustomLog /srv/www/newsino/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


File "/srv/www/django/myproj/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 230, in __call__
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]     self.load_middleware()
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]   File "/srv/www/django/myproj/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 40, in load_middleware
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]     mod = import_module(mw_module)
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]   File "/srv/www/django/myproj/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]     __import__(name)
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]   File "/srv/www/django/myproj/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_openid/consumer.py", line 14, in ?
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]     from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]   File "/srv/www/django/myproj/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 10, in ?
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]     from django.db.models.manager import Manager
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]   File "/srv/www/django/myproj/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 75, in ?
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]     connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]   File "/srv/www/django/myproj/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __getitem__
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]   File "/srv/www/django/myproj/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 32, in load_backend
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]     return import_module('.base', backend_name)
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]   File "/srv/www/django/myproj/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]     __import__(name)
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]   File "/srv/www/django/myproj/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 29, in ?
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55]     psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODE)
[Sun Aug 29 07:36:51 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55] SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

Comment: Give some specs on versions of software that you're using: mod_wsgi, python, apache.  Also try updating mod_wsgi to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

you shuld read the [doc](http://pinaxproject.com/docs/dev/gettingstarted/#installation) about the installation  and [this](http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?pid=12542) about the deploy.